# document.ready doesn't trigger until I move IE 10 window

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to resize some divs using JQuery, but it doesn't work until I move IE-10s window.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(WindowResize);
});

function WindowResize() {
    alert("FruitCrate: " + $("#FruitCrate").height()); 

    var n = Math.floor(window.innerHeight - 120);
    if (n < 190)
        n = 190;

    $("#FruitCrate").height(n);
}
```

As soon as I move window   document ready trigger's

What steps can i follow to figure out the issue.

Works fine on Chrome.

Comment: I'd consider it working on chrome to be a bug. Not a serious bug, but... why should the resize event be triggered when the window hasn't been resized.

Comment: How did you determine that `.ready()` specifically isn't triggering of the 2 events being used?

Comment: FYI, your function name shouldn't start with an uppercased letter if no constructor is used

Comment: Also, you don't need the document ready handler here, since the window will available long before that.

Comment: @KevinB n A Wolff, Thanks for your comments, I will implement the changes in code now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wouldn't, as the function is bound to the resize event and doesn't fire until you resize the window.
Add a trigger to trigger it on pageload as well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('resize', WindowResize).trigger('resize');
});
```

As a sidenote, the DOM ready handler isn't really needed, as the window is always available.

Comment: You are life saver, took me 6 hours to debug it, thanks, will accept as soon it will let me.

Comment: @yaron you should be aware of images not cached returning wrong height  if using document ready handler instead of window onload event. Maybe it will be your next question... ;)

Answer (score 2):

You'd have better to use window onload event instead, taking care about async content as images e.g:

```
$(window).on('load resize', WindowResize);
```

Comment: This one is a better solution than the accepted answer.